# Evaluate: $ F(\alpha) = \int_0^1 \frac{x^\alpha-1}{\ln x} dx $. Different answers from different approaches.

Tags: integration, leibniz-integral-rule

Why is approach 2 wrong here? I am relatively newe to calculus please explain in detail what is going wrong...
Evaluate: $ F(\alpha) = \int_0^1 \frac{x^\alpha-1}{\ln x} dx $

Approach 1: (Correct)

Using Newton Leibniz Theorem,
\begin{align}
 F'(\alpha) &= \int_0^1 \frac{\delta}{\delta\alpha} \left(\frac{x^\alpha-1}{\ln x}\right) dx \\
\implies F'(\alpha) &= \int_0^1 x^{\alpha} dx\\ 
\implies F'(\alpha) &= \frac{1}{\alpha+1} \\
\implies F(\alpha) &= \ln (\alpha+1) + c
\end{align}

We can get $ c=0 $ from $ F(0)=0 $, Hence
$$ F(\alpha) = \ln (\alpha+1)$$

Approach 2: (Incorrect)
$$F(\alpha) = \int_0^1 \frac{x^\alpha}{\ln x} dx - \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln x} dx $$
Substituite $ x^{\alpha+1}=t $
$$ F(\alpha) = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln t} dt - \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln x} dx $$
$$ F(\alpha) = 0 $$

Comment: The integral is valid near the right endpoint in the limit only. You can't exchange the integral of the difference with the difference of the integrals when that right end limit does not exist.

Comment: Is that the only mistake here? When my teacher was solving this question, he mentioned something about why the difference of integrals won't be 0 due to a non linear transform and hence we can't use this approach but I didn't get exactly why this was wrong...

Comment: I think if your integral ended at a value less than 1, you would probably see that they are both ok.

Comment: @Gregory I don't see how approach 2 would work with a value less than 1 either... For example is we take integration 0 to 0.5 wouldn't approach 2 still give 0 as the answer?

Comment: No. Your limits of integration would have changed.

Comment: @Gregory right. I totally missed that. Thanks for helping out

Comment: @TedShifrin it was $ F'(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\alpha+1} \implies F(\alpha) = \ln (\alpha+1) + C $ I simply integrated both sides with respect to $ \alpha $... I don't get what you're trying to say... I'm new to calculus so am not well versed with all the terminology etc. Also I didn't miss out on $ (\alpha+1)^2 $ in the denominator $ (\alpha+1) $ in both numerator and denominator and will get cancelled... I am sorry for not showing all the steps as I was in a hurry

Comment: @TedShifrin I just checked and I don't see why there would be two of them in the denominator $ x^\alpha dx = \frac{dt}{\alpha+1} $ will produce one in the denominator and $ \ln x = \frac{1}{\alpha + 1} \ln t $ will produce on in the numerator... Also I am sorry I didn't know i had that type and someone edited it for me...

Comment: @ТymaGaidash٠ I think I got your point about splitting the integral but how did you get that using the substitution? I'm not getting the same integral.. where did the ln x go?

Comment: @AkshitChhabra There was a differentiation error. We should get $\int_0^1\frac{1-t^{\frac1{a+1}-1}}{\ln(t)}dt$

Comment: @ТymaGaidash٠ yes, that's right, thank you for helping me.

Comment: Something that is often overlooked in Calculus is that to apply a theorem like Newton-Leibnitz you need to make sure that its hypotheses are fulfilled.

Comment: The theorem you fatally misapplied was not Newton-Leibnitz (though it doesn't apply directly here since $F$ is improper at both its endpoints, this can be worked around), but rather the theorem $\int (f+g) = \int f + \int g$. That theorem only holds if at least one of $\int f$ or $\int g$ is finite.