# Evaluating $ \int_0^1 \frac{x^a - 1}{\ln{}x} dx$

Tags: calculus

I know how to evaluate using Leibnitz Rule

I was trying to see if I could solve it without that

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{x^a - 1}{\ln{}x} dx$ = $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{x^a}{\ln{}x} dx$ - $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln{}x} dx$

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{x^a}{\ln{}x} dx$ - $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln{}x} dx$ = $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{(a+1)x^a}{\ln{}x^{a+1}} dx$ - $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln{}x} dx$

Substituting $x^{a+1} = t$ in the 1st integral we get
$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln{}t} dt$ - $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln{}x} dx$
= $0$

Where am I going wrong??

Also any other ways to evaluate this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4776550/evaluate-f-alpha-int-01-fracx-alpha-1-ln-x-dx-different-answer?noredirect=1#comment10149669_4776550) from a few days ago.

Comment: Well an immediate error is in your very first equality. How do you know that you can split the integral like that? You need to show that each individual integral converges.

Comment: @ТymaGaidash٠ Could you provide a link to the Question? It would be really helpful

Comment: @JinanshDalal You wanted a link and the link is in the top comment. Do you see it?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash٠ Yep..Thanks!!

Comment: @PrincessEev Yeah got it..Thanks!!

Comment: @JinanshDalal, the integral $\int_0^1\!\frac1{\ln x}\mathrm dx$ does not converge, so you cannot split the original integral in two parts as you did.

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{x^a-1}{\ln x}\mathrm dx=\ln(a+1)\;$ for any $\,a>-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the issue you're running into with your approach is that you have taken a convergent integral and split it up into two divergent integrals.

For another approach we first define
$$
I=\int_0^1\frac{x^a-1}{\log x}\,\mathrm dx.
$$
Expanding $x^a=e^{a\log x}$ yields
$$
I=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a^k}{k!}\int_0^1\log^{k-1}x\,\mathrm dx=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-a)^k}{k!}\int_0^1(-\log x)^{k-1}\,\mathrm dx.
$$
A substitution of $u=-\log x$ turns the remaining integral into a gamma function giving
$$
I=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-a)^k}{k!}(k-1)!=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-a)^k}{k}=\log(1+a),
$$
which follows form the series expansion of the logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, if $I(a)$ is the integral we're looking for, $$\frac{dI}{da}(a)=\int_0^1x^a dx = \frac 1 {1+a}$$
Thus $$I(a)-I(0) = I(a)=\log(1+a)$$